# Regex for a simple decimal

Tags: regex

Google Sheets colors a number in blue in its formula syntax:

[image]

It seems like the requirements are:

- It can only contain numbers and an optional period
- It cannot contain more than one period
- It cannot contain anything else

My first stab this was:

- [`\b[0-9.]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/aOjfMc/1)

But this of course allows multiple `.`'s which I don't want. For example, it would allow `123.128.129.00`. What would be a better regex for this?

Comment: Put the dot after + operator, then definitely again allow the user to enter digits.

Comment: What about `.123` and `123.`? Are they valid decimals?

Comment: @PM77-1 did you actually look at that duplicate you posted? That's validating a single number, not multiple numbers in a formula string. Which answer did you think was applicable?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, I'm not really interested in "how to validate a number" but moreso "what is the regex for numeric validation that Google Sheets uses".

Comment: @PM77-1 here's a visual: https://imgur.com/a/X9G9xaB.

Comment: You (yourself) presented a single number regex. If you are interested in something else then make an effort to be clear.

Comment: @PM77-1 agreed, thank you for the clarification. How does this answer look? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64519055/12283168